# How do I position an object with a Lat/Lng in ARCore view?

Tags: android, arcore

Given that I have the users Latitude and Longitude and I have an object's position too how can I translate these coordinates to something that can be seen in it's correct relative position in ARCore?

I've tried this..
https://github.com/appoly/ARCore-Location
But, unfortuntately it doesnt quite work.

Basically, how would I transform Lat/Lng into pos and rotation below?

```
Session session = arFragment.getArSceneView().getSession();
float[] pos = { 0,0,-1 };     
float[] rotation = {0,0,0,1}
Anchor anchor =  session.createAnchor(new Pose(pos, rotation));        
anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);
anchorNode.setRenderable(flag);        
anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
```

Comment: do you want to put the AR object on the specific coordinates or put the object in front of the user when he is in the specific place?

Comment: I want to put the ar object at the coordinates.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @MarkSheekey, have you been able to figure out this problem? Actually, I need to place static objects at a given point of interest.
It will be great if anyone can suggest something. thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the AR object at the coordinates you need to:
1. check in each frame does the coordinates are in your field of view

2. count the distance from user coordinates to the ar coordinates
3. make a translation to the ar world - for example, you can find in google an example of how to count distance using arcore. You can use this to count the distance from user to the ar object place
4. based on the info above place the ar object on a specific object

remember that counting distance can be used also for scaling to make it as real as possible. For example when the object is far away it should be small, if the user is closer it should be bigger

Comment: "you can find in google an example of how to count distance using arcore" is not helpful advice

Answer (score 0):

I recently developed a functionality to get this working without using any external system.

Here's the link to my repository: https://github.com/bhaskarblur/ARCore-Navigation-Anchors-using-LatLng-in-AR-World---Android

Read the Readme of repository to understand how it works.

This app uses ARCore with Sceneform to support AR & render objects in AR World. The current location of user is continuously calculated and also the yaw(azimuth) aka the rotation of the device around it's -z axis which is respective to north. Now, we have our current Latitude, Longitude & our rotation so we assume that we are an origin point on graph (0,0) and we added a Latitude & Longitude of a coordinate into the graph say it's (3,3). So, we convert this (3,3) via a CoordinateHelper class which converts LatLng into local coordinates using our current location, yaw and the target Location. Now we got the local coordinates, we set this as a LocalPosition to our AnchorNode in AR World.

Do leave an upvote if it helped you!